# Elasticsearch multi-match fields doesn't include query string

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, filter, analyzer

I am doing a multi-match search using the following query object:

```
{
    _source: [
        'baseline',
        'cdrp',
        'date',
        'description',
        'dev_status',
        'element',
        'event',
        'id'
    ],
    track_total_hits: true,
    query: {
        bool: {
            filter: [{name: "baseline", values: ["1f.0.1.0", "1f.1.8.3"]}],
            should: [
                {
                    multi_match:{
                        query: "national",
                        fields: ["cdrp","description","narrative.*","title","cop"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 
    },
    highlight: { fields: { '*': {} } },
    sort: [],
    from: 0,
    size: 50
}
```

I'm expecting the word "national" to be found within description or narrative.* fields but only one record out of 2 returned meet my expectations. I'm trying to understand why.

**elasticsearch.config.ts**

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "search_synonyms": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                    "graph_synonyms",
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ],
            }
        }
    }
},

"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
        },
        "narrative": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "_all":{
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "search_synonyms"
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Share sample docs too.

Comment: @shAkur multi_match query is part of should clause, so it will only affect scoring. All the documents will be returned. Document which have "national" will be scored higher. If you intend to filter on "national" , you should move it under filter clause

Comment: I want filters to be ANDed with the description and narrative.* fields, so the word "national" should be in one of the text fields. Moving multi_match object within filter would do the trick or it'd be better to use must instead?

Answer (score 0):

Should clause works like OR, it doesn't filter out documents it affects scoring. Documents which match should clause are scored higher.

If you want to filter on multi-match you can move it inside filter clause

```
filter: [
           {
              name: "baseline", values: ["1f.0.1.0", "1f.1.8.3"]
           },
           {
               multi_match:
               {
                     query: "national",
                     fields: ["cdrp","description","narrative.*","title","cop"]
               }
           }
        ]
```

Filter vs Must:- Both return documents matching clauses specified. Filter doesn't score documents. So if you are not interested in score of documents or are not concerned with order of documents returned, you can use filter. So both are same with difference of scoring.

Documents with more matches are scored higher

[Multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) by default uses [best_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)

> Finds documents which match any field, but uses the _score from the
>   best field.

It uses score returned for field with maximum number of matches to calculate score for each document.

Example

Document 1 has matches in two field , field1 (score 2), field2 (score 1)

Document 2 has matches in one field , field2 (score 3)

Documnet 2 will be ranked higher even if 1 field has matched.

You can change it to most_fields

> Finds documents which match any field and combines the _score from
>   each field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [],
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Still  a document with fewer number of fields matched can be ranked higher due to high score in a field caused by multiple terms.

If you want to give same score to a single field irrespective of number of tokens matched. You need to use [constant_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "field1": "test"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "field2": "test"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  }
},
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "field1": {},
      "field2": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "iSCe6nEB8J88APx3YBGn",
        "_score" : 2.0, --> one score per field matched
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "test",
          "field2" : "test"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "field1" : [
            "<em>test</em>"
          ],
          "field2" : [
            "<em>test</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "iiCe6nEB8J88APx3ghF-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "test",
          "field2" : "abc"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "field1" : [
            "<em>test</em>"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index18",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "iyCf6nEB8J88APx3UhF8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "test do",
          "field2" : "abc"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "field1" : [
            "<em>test</em> do"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Document scoring is important, however I'll have to change that and use the number of highlights for each document to built the score. Do you know how can I accomplish that?

Comment: @shAkur By default more the number of matches higher the score

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case for my results. For a search I am getting 3 results: first one has 3 highlights, second has one highlight and the third one has 2 highlights. I need them to be ordered based on number of highlights found

Comment: @shAkur Can you add  query you are executing in question

Comment: Its the same query I put in the first code snippet above, but with an empty `query.bool.filter` and "this is a really really long text field" as `multi_match query`. I think the default sorting algorithm is based on the relevance and not by the number of highlights. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213315/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-shakur).